# Why does fputs() require a constant as first parameter and not fputc()?

Tags: c, function, parameters, declaration, definition

```c
int fputc(int c, FILE *stream);

int fputs(const char *s, FILE *stream);
```

Why isn't `const int c` required in fputc()'s declaration?

Comment: Because `fputc` couldn't change `c` for outside of it even if it really wanted to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `const` modifier prevents the function from changing the input parameter.

`fputc` function uses `int c` as input which is a value type. Because parameters are passed by value, the function can only change the internal copy, it could not change the original value.

`fputs` function uses `char *s` as input which is a pointer type, so the pointed memory could be changed by the function. The `const` modifier protects the pointed memory by preventing the function from changing it.

**Note 1:** The `const` modifier in function `fputs` is on the `char` type (`const char *s`), which means the pointed memory cannot be changed. If the `const` was on the input parameter `s` (`char * const s`), it would not protect the pointed memory, it would only protect the pointer itself which is anyway passed by value.

**Note 2:** As mentioned by [Eric Postpischil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/298225/eric-postpischil) in the comment and shown in [Vlad from Moscow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2877241/vlad-from-moscow)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57273894/10927863), if the const modifier is in the functions declaration and not in the functions definition, it has no effect.

Comment: A `const` modifier to a parameter (the actual parameter, not a subcomponent, *e.g.*, `char * const s`, not `const char *s`) in a function declaration that is not a definition has no effect; it does not prevent the function from changing the parameter. (The argument cannot be changed [directly], of course, since it is passed by value. But functions can change their parameters unless they are defined with `const`.)

Answer (score 7):

There's no point in marking parameters as `const` in a function declaration. Arguments are passed by value, so the parameter is a copy anyway. It doesn't affect how the function can be called.

However, `const char *s` does not mean `s` is `const`. What this declaration means is that `s` is a pointer to a `const char`; i.e. the `fputs` function promises not to write through the pointer it is given. Also, there is an implicit conversion from `char *` to `const char *` (but not vice versa), meaning that `fputs` can be called with both read-only and writeable strings.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to make the first parameter `const`; the "top level" of arguments are copied, not referenced, so all `const` would do is prevent the called function from modifying its own copy of the argument.

Similarly, note that only the values being pointed to are `const` for `fputs`; the parameter isn't `const char *const s` because the extra const-ness would only limit the callee's ability to modify where its copy of the pointer points to; the `const` guarantee is only applied to the (shared) values being pointed to.

Comment: Putting `const` in `int fputc(int c, FILE *stream);` would not prevent `fputc` from modifying its copy of `c`. `const` in declarations that are not definitions has no effect.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: I assume you mean that the definition of `fputc` is what would determine if it is `const` or not, not merely the prototype declaration? Because it will definitely complain if you define a function taking `const int c` and try to modify `c` within it (e.g. gcc dies with `error: assignment of read-only parameter ‘c’`).

Answer (score 0):

`const char *s` doesn't mean that `s` must point to a constant. It means that `fputs` is not allowed to modify what is pointed to by `s`.

Answer (score 0):

When the compiler determines a function type then high level qualifiers of parameters are discarded.

So these two function declarations

```
int fputc(int c, FILE *stream);
int fputc( const int c, FILE *stream);
```

declare the same one function.

And these two function declarations

```
int fputs(const char *s, FILE *stream);
int fputs(const char * const s, FILE *stream);
```

also declare the same one function.

So the high-level qualifier const has a meaning not for the user of the function but only for the internal definition of the function. In any case a corresponding argument is passed by value that is the function deals with a copy of the argument. So whether inside the function the copy will have the qualifier const or will not does not matter for the user of the function.

Consider the following demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h> 

void f( const int x );

void f( int x )
{
    x += 10;

    printf( "Inside the function x = %d\n", x );
}    


int main( void )  
{ 
    int x = 1;

    printf( "Before calling f x = %d\n", x );

    f( x );

    printf( "After calling f  x = %d\n", x );
}
```

Its output is

```
Before calling f x = 1
Inside the function x = 11
After calling f  x = 1
```

So it does not matter for the user of the function whether the parameter x of the function has the qualifier const. The both declarations declare the same one function from the point of view of the compiler (and the user of the function).

Function parameters are their local variables. And users do not bother whether or not some local variables will be declared within the function with the qualifier const.

Pat attention to that in this declaration

```
int fputs(const char *s, FILE *stream);
```

it is not the first parameter that is declared as constant. It is data pointed by the pointer that is constant.

But in this declaration

```
int fputc( const int c, FILE *stream);
```

the parameter itself that is constant.